# In Zig, what is the right way to iterate over the fields of an enum?

Tags: zig

I'm trying to iterate over all the fields in an Enum (really I just want to the values), in my `enum` in Zig:

```
const std = @import("std");

const MyEnum = enum(u8) {
    NONE = 0,
    ONE,
    TWO,
};

pub fn main() void {
    std.debug.assert(@typeInfo(MyEnum).Enum.fields.len == 3);
    std.debug.assert(std.mem.eql(u8, @typeInfo(MyEnum).Enum.fields[0].name, "NONE"));
    std.debug.assert(@typeInfo(MyEnum).Enum.fields[0].value == 0);

    for (std.meta.fields(MyEnum)) |f| {
        std.debug.print("{}\n", .{ f.value });
    }

    for (@typeInfo(MyEnum).Enum.fields) |f| {
        std.debug.print("{}\n", .{ f.value });
    }
}
```

The asserts at the top just show I've got the basics right.  Neither of the `for` loops compile, I get:

```
... error: values of type '[]const builtin.Type.EnumField' must be comptime-known, but index value is runtime-known
```

AFAICT, all the content of the enum is "comptime-known", so I'm not sure why the error is complaining about `EnumField`...

I'm running a locally-built zig 0.12.0-dev.1782+dd188307b sync'd in the last couple of days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is not very good because it's actually coming from your `for` statement. It's the index that statement uses that's not comptime known. Use `inline for` instead to run the loop at compile time:

```
const std = @import("std");

const MyEnum = enum(u8) {
    NONE = 0,
    ONE,
    TWO,
};

pub fn main() void {
    std.debug.assert(@typeInfo(MyEnum).Enum.fields.len == 3);
    std.debug.assert(std.mem.eql(u8, @typeInfo(MyEnum).Enum.fields[0].name, "NONE"));
    std.debug.assert(@typeInfo(MyEnum).Enum.fields[0].value == 0);

    inline for (std.meta.fields(MyEnum)) |f| {
        std.debug.print("{}\n", .{f.value});
    }

    inline for (@typeInfo(MyEnum).Enum.fields) |f| {
        std.debug.print("{}\n", .{f.value});
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, now the bit about "index value" in the error makes more sense... I hadn't realized the enum metadata is strictly available at comptime.

Comment: @P.T. in general any type of meta/type information is only available at compile time, because otherwise you'd always incur the overhead of storing it even when you don't need it.